# Redirect using web.config file when there is no pathname

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio

I've been working on a ASP.NET web application project in Visual Studio. In that project, when the user enters the hostname they get a 404 error but what I would like to happen is for them to be redirected to the index.html when they have just entered the hostname.

Below is the code that I tried using but it didn't work. It said there were too many redirects which I think has something to do with the path value being empty

```
<location path="">
    <system.webServer>
       <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="index.html" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Does anyone have an suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MVC you could create a default route but since you asked for a way to do it in web.config try:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="index.html" mode="On">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="index.html"/>
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I've just realised the code snippet I put in wasn't right. I've changed it now and wondered if it would change your answer.

Comment: @LM2016: not much :) change the page to index.html - also shouldn't this be **default.aspx** since you are using an asp.net application?

Comment: Thanks for your help! Relatively new to this so it's very much appreciated

Comment: @LM2016 if this answer helped you solve your problem please consider making it the accepted answer by checking the green mark

Comment: I had already accepted it but it hadn't registered. That's it now.